# i tried to write xlsx workbook in S3 bucket while creating EC2(Python) but got errors. how i can resolve the errors?

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, jupyter-notebook

my codes are pasted below and got errors one is "FileCreateError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:" and second is "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:". i gave many hit and trials to it but not able to resolve it. i can write the csv file in same path how come i got the error "no such file or directory".

```
writer = ExcelWriter("s3a://ihsm-dl-automotive-dev/auto_target_marketing_data/Testing- 
         sandbox/PP_PROCESS_TESTING_DEEPAK/PARAMETER_FINAL_N.xlsx")
CONTRIBUTION[['VARNAME', 'CONTRIBUTION']].to_excel(writer, sheet_name='CONTRIBUTION', index=False )
PARAMETER_V2_N.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='CEOF', index=False)
Indiviual_variables_above_25[['VARNAME','CONTRIBUTION']].to_excel(writer,sheet_name='Indiviual_variables_above_25%', index=False)
writer.save()
```

Sample code with dataframe:-

```
index1 = pd.DataFrame({'ARANK':['001', '002', '003', '004', '005', '006', '007', '008', '009', '010', '011', '012', '013', '014', '015', '016', '017', '018', '019', '020', '021', '022', '023', '024', '025', '026', '027', '028', '029', '030', '031', '032', '033', '034', '035', '036', '037', '038', '039', '040', '041', '042', '043', '044', '045', '046', '047', '048', '049', '050', '051', '052', '053', '054', '055', '056', '057', '058', '059', '060', '061', '062', '063', '064', '065', '066', '067', '068', '069', '070', '071', '072', '073', '074', '075', '076', '077', '078', '079', '080', '081', '082', '083', '084', '085', '086', '087', '088', '089', '090', '091', '092', '093', '094', '095', '096', '097', '098', '099', '100'],
                       'TEST_RNKINDEX':[723 , 628 , 558 , 506 , 522 , 464 , 406 , 363 , 372 , 311 , 279 , 260 , 237 , 235 , 245 , 208 , 211 , 189 , 154 , 198 , 184 , 149 , 147 , 178 , 142 , 150 , 141 , 136 , 125 , 108 , 119 , 122 , 106 , 119 , 102 , 96 , 97 , 98 , 90 , 89 , 88 , 74 , 79 , 98 , 78 , 74 , 87 , 84 , 80 , 67 , 61 , 58 , 66 , 53 , 69 , 55 , 54 , 63 , 51 , 49 , 50 , 46 , 60 , 49 , 48 , 46 , 49 , 46 , 40 , 53 , 42 , 42 , 37 , 39 , 50 , 37 , 39 , 39 , 32 , 31 , 31 , 36 , 35 , 29 , 29 , 29 , 21 , 34 , 24 , 30 , 30 , 24 , 26 , 14 , 18 , 16 , 18 , 18 , 17 , 13],
                       'VALID_RNKINDEX':[717 , 617 , 602 , 548 , 486 , 451 , 424 , 410 , 338 , 302 , 327 , 264 , 218 , 249 , 227 , 206 , 193 , 197 , 164 , 144 , 195 , 173 , 218 , 202 , 159 , 156 , 142 , 138 , 133 , 108 , 137 , 121 , 100 , 115 , 129 , 104 , 113 , 92 , 76 , 69 , 77 , 79 , 69 , 83 , 81 , 65 , 69 , 39 , 74 , 64 , 60 , 53 , 76 , 70 , 50 , 55 , 61 , 57 , 41 , 50 , 42 , 53 , 58 , 64 , 39 , 38 , 44 , 48 , 60 , 29 , 53 , 48 , 52 , 52 , 39 , 29 , 18 , 60 , 41 , 42 , 28 , 29 , 32 , 29 , 34 , 27 , 30 , 25 , 27 , 19 , 21 , 28 , 21 , 18 , 22 , 23 , 15 , 13 , 19 , 13],
                       'EFFECT_SIZE':[0.04 , 0.08 , -0.31 , -1.3 , -0.7 , 0.09 , 1.3 , 0.7, 0.24 , 0.06 , -0.34 , -0.03 , 0.13 , -0.1 , 0.13 , 0.01 , 0.13 , -0.06 , -0.07 , 0.38 , -0.08 , -0.17 , -0.5 , -0.17 , -0.12 , -0.04 , -0.01 , -0.01 , -0.06 , 0 , -0.13 , 0.01 , 0.04 , 0.03 , -0.19 , -0.06 , -0.11 , 0.04 , 0.1 , 0.14 , 0.08 , -0.04 , 0.07 , 0.11 , -0.02 , 0.06 , 0.13 , 0.32 , 0.04 , 0.02 , 0.01 , 0.04 , -0.07 , -0.12 , 0.13 , 0 , -0.05 , 0.04 , 0.07 , -0.01 , 0.06 , -0.05 , 0.01 , -0.11 , 0.06 , 0.06 , 0.04 , -0.01 , -0.14 , 0.17 , -0.08 , -0.04 , -0.11 , -0.09 , 0.08 , 0.06 , 0.15 , -0.15 , -0.06 , -0.08 , 0.02 , 0.8 , 0.02 , 0 , -0.04 , 0.01 , -0.06 , 0.06 , -0.02 , 0.08 , 0.06 , -0.03 , 0.04 , -0.03 , -0.03 , -0.05 , 0.02 , 0.04 , -0.01 , 0]})


com_index = pd.DataFrame({'SCORE_GROUP':['1-10', '11-20', '21-30', '31-40', '41-50', '51-60', '61-70', '71-80', '81-90', '91-100'],
                          'TEST_RNKINDEX':[492, 224, 142, 104, 81, 58, 49, 38, 30, 18],
                          'VALID_RNKINDEX':[492, 221, 155, 106, 70, 57, 48, 43, 28, 18],
                          'EFFECT_SIZE':[0, 0.02, -0.09, -0.01, 0.08, 0.01, 0.01, -0.03, 0.01, 0]})



writer = pd.ExcelWriter('s3a://ihsm-dl-automotive-dev/auto_target_marketing_data/Testing-sandbox/PP_PROCESS_TESTING_DEEPAK/filename.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter', options={'tmpdir': 's3a://ihsm-dl-automotive-dev/auto_target_marketing_data/Testing-sandbox/PP_PROCESS_TESTING_DEEPAK/'})
com_index.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='CONTRIBUTION', index=False )
index1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='CEOF', index=False)
writer.save()
```

logs:-

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/xlsxwriter/workbook.py in close(self)
    315             try:
--> 316                 self._store_workbook()
    317             except IOError as e:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/xlsxwriter/workbook.py in _store_workbook(self)
    633         except IOError as e:
--> 634             raise e
    635 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/xlsxwriter/workbook.py in _store_workbook(self)
    631             xlsx_file = ZipFile(self.filename, "w", compression=ZIP_DEFLATED,
--> 632                                 allowZip64=self.allow_zip64)
    633         except IOError as e:

/usr/lib/python3.7/zipfile.py in __init__(self, file, mode, compression, allowZip64, compresslevel)
   1203                 try:
-> 1204                     self.fp = io.open(file, filemode)
   1205                 except OSError:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 's3a://ihsm-dl-automotive-dev/auto_target_marketing_data/Testing-sandbox/PP_PROCESS_TESTING_DEEPAK/PARAMETER_FINAL_N.xlsx'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

FileCreateError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-e608b4f3e445> in <module>
      8 # else:
      9 #     df_blnk.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sum_of_variables_above_40%', index=False)
---> 10 writer.save()

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/excel/_xlsxwriter.py in save(self)
    193         """
    194 
--> 195         return self.book.close()
    196 
    197     def write_cells(

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/xlsxwriter/workbook.py in close(self)
    316                 self._store_workbook()
    317             except IOError as e:
--> 318                 raise FileCreateError(e)
    319             except LargeZipFile as e:
    320                 raise FileSizeError("Filesize would require ZIP64 extensions. "

FileCreateError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 's3a://ihsm-dl-automotive-dev/auto_target_marketing_data/Testing-sandbox/PP_PROCESS_TESTING_DEEPAK/PARAMETER_FINAL_N.xlsx'
```

TIA

Comment: The first thing to check is whether the directory "s3a://ihsm-dl-automotive-dev/auto_target_marketing_data/Testing-sandbox/" exists. Pandas/XlsxWriter won't create the parent directory if it doesn't exist. If it does exist check if you have write permissions in that directory, for example create a program that creates a simple text file in the same location.

Comment: Yes, path is exit and have the permission as well..write csv file in the same path.

Comment: Can you try adding these options to ExcelWriter: `pd.ExcelWriter('path/filename.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter', options={'strings_to_urls': False})` and/or `pd.ExcelWriter('path/filename.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter', options={'tmpdir': 'writeable/path'})`

Comment: in both cases i am getting the same error. 
my code :- 
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('s3a://ihsm-dl-automotive-dev/auto_target_marketing_data/Testing-sandbox/PP_PROCESS_TESTING_DEEPAK/filename.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter', options={'tmpdir': 'writeable/s3a://ihsm-dl-automotive-dev/auto_target_marketing_data/Testing-sandbox/PP_PROCESS_TESTING_DEEPAK/'})
com_index.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='CONTRIBUTION', index=False )
index1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='CEOF', index=False)
writer.save()

Comment: The `tmpdir` option shouldn’t have the word `writeable` in it. It should just be a path to a writeable directory.

Comment: nopes same error... writer = pd.ExcelWriter('s3a://ihsm-dl-automotive-dev/auto_target_marketing_data/Testing-sandbox/PP_PROCESS_TESTING_DEEPAK/filename.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter', options={'tmpdir': 's3a://ihsm-dl-automotive-dev/auto_target_marketing_data/Testing-sandbox/PP_PROCESS_TESTING_DEEPAK/'})
                                                             com_index.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='CONTRIBUTION', index=False )
index1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='CEOF', index=False)
writer.save()

Comment: Then I don't have anymore guesses. The error corresponds to the error you get when the directory doesn't exist. If you are 100% sure the directory does exist then I don't know what the issue is.

Comment: okay,  i really appreciate your efforts